# efficient way to understand that a curve is closed or not

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computational-geometry

what is the efficient way to understand that a curve is closed or not?

maybe one way is flood fill algorithm and use it to check it ;If your flood fill leaves a pre-determined bounding box, you are outside the shape. Otherwise if your flood fill terminates, then you're within the shape.

but is it an efficient way?

tnx.

Comment: How is the curve represented?

Comment: Your floodfill proposal might fail for self-intersecting curves - imagine a figure 8 with an open top, if you choose to floodfill the bottom loop, you might decide that the curve is closed.

Comment: the curve is represented as an array of pixels. suppose a curve in a paint app.for a curve like 8 , I'll represent it as two curves.

Answer (score 2):

Look at a curve as a graph, vertices are pixels and edges are between neighbouring pixels. Testing is done:

- Simple curve is if all vertices have two neighbours and graph is connected.
- More not intersected simple curves is if all vertices have two neighbours and graph isn't connected. Number of part is find with graph partitioning.
- 8 curve is if all vertices except one have 2 neighbours, that one have 4 neighbours, and graph is connected.
- ...

Testing graph/subgraph connectivity and partitioning is done by graph traversal.

Comment: i thinks that looking as graph will increase time complexity, doesn't it?

Comment: No. It is same to look on it as graph or pixel problem. Define problem in graph terms is only more clear. To check is curve closed or which type it is, you have to check connectivity, simplicity (2 neighbours) and/or self-intersection (more neighbours). All of these checks are same in graph terms and in pixel terms. There is only memory requirement if whole graph is stored. But it is enough to store only set of pixels and calculate connectivity on the fly since for pixel neighbours only few pixels have to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you walk along the curve with two separate pointers?
If so, do that and set one pointer to traverse twice as fast.
If the loop is closed, the pointers will overlap at one point.

Answer (score 0):

This should be O(n)..

Lets say the degree of each pixel is the number of pixels in its neighborhood.

Walk through your pixel array, 
if any pixel has odd degree, then the curve is not closed.

*Explanation:* 
For an even degree pixel, for each path that enters, there is a path that leaves it.
This is not true for odd degrees.